# Number of flip flop generated the Verilog code

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl, digital-logic, vlsi

How to count the number of flip-flops generated or used in the Verilog code without using any tool?

[image]

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: for a small piece of code, the number of times the clock edge is getting triggered, I am calculating the change in variables which can give me a rough count of the number of flops that might be getting used while running the code. but if we have a large number of variables which is changing simultaneously then how to check the number of flops in the code?

Comment: It's impossible to help you since you have not provided any code of what you're trying to do. SO is not a code writing service, so you need to provide code and links to the relevant sources you are using, yourself.

Comment: Sorry sir, code is very big, I will be not able to provide you code

Comment: It is very difficult to calculate the number of flops manually, in particular in the big models. There are generate blocks which you need evaluate manually. there are optimizations which could  alter number of flops. There are complicated always blocks where is difficult to figure out the outcome. So, all your attempts will be just a rough estimation in the best case.

Comment: I have attached snippet of my code. Can you use it as a reference to 
explain to me how to proceed to count the number of FFs used

Answer (score 0):

You count the number of bits on the LHS of non-blocking assignments inside an always @ (pos/neg_edge ...). (The 'non-blocking' adjective is superfluous as you should only have non-blocking assignments inside an @ (pos/neg_edge clock) section.)

The following code produces 12 registers:

```
reg [7:0] my_byte1,my_byte2;
...
always @(posedge clock)
begin
   my_byte1     <= something_which_is_8_bits_wide;
   my_byte2[3:0]<= something_else_which_is_4_bits_wide;
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this.